# Open app from AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

First of all let me say that I'm new to AWS and don't know much about servers but trying to learn something now!

I have been given access to AWS instance. I can access the server using `ssh`. It's ubuntu server.

There is an application deployed under `var/www/`. I have also public IP of server but when I try to access this public IP it's not opening and I also can't ping that IP.

Am I doing something wrong? I will note that I don't have very big experience with servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check security group credentials associated with your ec2. There http and any other required protocols will need to be opened.  And also that internet gateway is correctly NATed. Good luck. It's a steep but fast learning curve with aws.